# Can't fill hash in Ruby on Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working on an application and I need to fill in a hash with empty values if it does not already have values. @pet[] contains 3 hashes,  each should have a :name, :age and :pet_type_id. The purpose of this variable is to use it to fill select_tags in the view, as follows:

```
<%= text_field_tag "pet[][name]", @pet_storage[t].name %>&nbsp;
<%= text_field_tag "pet[][age]", @pet_storage[t].age %>&nbsp;
<%= select_tag("pet[][pet_type_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(PetType.all, "id", "name", @pet_storage[t].pet_type_id), :prompt => 'Select a pet type') %>
```

This will provide default data for my form. If the default data doesnt exist, I need it to just be empty (which is why I'm trying to fill the @pet_storage with hashes that contain the name, age and pet_type_id keys with empty string values.

This is the code that I am using in my controller:

```
unless defined?(@pet_storage)
@pet_storage = Array.new
RecordsHelper::ALLOWED_PETS.times { |t| @pet_storage[t] = {name:'', age:'', pet_type_id:''}}
end
```

However, I get this error

```
undefined method `name' for {:name=>"", :age=>"", :pet_type_id=>""}:Hash
Extracted source (around line #15):

12:         <%= f2.label :age %>&nbsp;
13:         <%= f2.label :pet_type_id, 'Type of pet'%>
14:         </br>
15:         <%= text_field_tag "pet[][name]", @pet_storage[t].name %>&nbsp;
16:         <%= text_field_tag "pet[][age]", @pet_storage[t].age %>&nbsp;
17:         <%= select_tag("pet[][pet_type_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(PetType.all, "id", "name",     @pet_storage[t].pet_type_id), :prompt => 'Select a pet type') %>
18:     </div>
```

Why cant I save these values on my hash? Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: You use `name` as a method, but should use it as a key. The same is for `age`. ;)

Comment: Here name, age and pet_type_id are keys of that hash. You can't access these with dot operator. see my answer.

Comment: You are right, fixed that using the response below

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = []

3.times do |i|
  arr[i] = {a: 1, b: 2}
end

puts arr[2][:a]  #=>1

puts arr[2].a

1.rb:7:in `<main>': undefined method `a' for {:a=>1, :b=>2}:Hash (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't realized the difference

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way. I hope your intention is to fill with corresponding value of object if exist, or else blank. Pass `pet_storage.try(:name)` as value. This will fetch value if exist or else return nil which inturn displays blank. similarly you can pass value for other atributes: `age` and `pet_type_id`

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing a hash as though the keys are methods on it which is explained by this error

> undefined method `name' for {:name=>"", :age=>"", :pet_type_id=>""}:Hash

There's a few ways to fix this.  One thing you can try is to use a `Struct` instead of a hash to initialize `@pet_storage` but I think that's overkill.  The easiest way is to check if `@pet_storage` exists first

```
<%= text_field_tag "pet[][name]", @pet_storage ? @pet_storage[t].name : '' %>&nbsp;
```

This way, you don't have to set anything in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

"name" is a key of @pet_storage[t] Hash. So you have to access like

```
@pet_storage[t][:name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Code smell.

Forget Hash here, or you are going to make endless hacking.

The correct way to set default value is to set the instance variable value in controller level, or even model level.

Then in View, just refer to the instance variable's attributes/methods normally.

For example

```
# In controller
@pet.name = "Dog"

# In view
<%= form_for @pet %>
  <%= text_field_for :name %>
```

Then in browser the text field will pre filled with "Dog". Simple.